# Shell Scripting | Bash Programming | Custom right click in nautilus

Tags: python, bash, shell, nautilus

I am trying to make a custom right click command for nautilus. 
I managed to find a useful content [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186509/how-do-i-make-a-custom-right-click-command-for-nautilus/186513).

What I don't understand is what does these two lines essentially mean ?

```
IFS_BAK=$IFS
IFS="
"
```

And these are present at the bottom too. What do they mean ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFS_BAK` is essentially creating a backup of existing value of `IFS` variable.
The next line then assigns a new value to `IFS` i.e specific/required the script.
More info on Internal Field Separator (IFS) can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. 
It is called an 'Internal Field Separator', a special variable in shell.

If you set IFS to | (i.e. IFS=| ), | will be treated as delimiters between words/fields when splitting a line of input.

In the first line:

```
IFS_BAK=$IFS
```

the initial 'IFS' value is stored in the variable 'IFS_BAK' and the value of IFS is set to 'new line' by

```
IFS="
"
```

so that the entire line is treated as a 'single input'.

Later, at the end of the program, the IFS value is restored to what it was originally.